# How to get rid of blinking cursor box in python?

Tags: python, intellij-idea

I am using the newest version of python through Intellij idea.
I am sure I pressed a key bind but my text cursor is different now:

[image: Here is the cursor now:]

What do I have to do to get it back to normal?

Comment: This is not specific to python and a common feature of many text editors where regular text insert mode is denoted by a "normal" cursor, and overtype mode is denoted by a block cursor. overtype mode is commonly toggled with the insert key.

Answer (score 5):

Try pressing the "Insert" key on your keyboard (may be abbreviated "ins")

Answer (score 1):

File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance disable "Use block caret"
If that does not work, try pressing the "Insert" key on your keyboard..

Comment: @Ronin The first one or the second one? I would appreciate if you could approve my answer by pressing the V next to it :) It's important for the community to mark questions as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the IdeaVim plugin installed, disable it to get it back to normal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press the (M1) / (Insert) or (INS) key.